PowerApps not playing updated version
A bit strange. But when I hit play on my power app, it’s playing an older version. It doesn’t play my most updated edits. Anybody know why this might be?

When you play as in preview while in Edit mode? If hitting play outside of Edit mode, then it will play the last Published version. You will need to publish it to see the latest. Even then it will take a minute for it to update, you usually get a banner saying that new version is available and to refresh.

Yup. Thats it. Haha thanks
